# C# Computing Thread block and wait time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In the JVM, one can enable thread contention monitoring and get back statistics on blockedTime, blockedCount, waitedTime and waitedCount. (Reference files from openJDK - [ThreadImpl class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/management/ThreadImpl.java) and [ThreadInfo class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.java#ThreadInfo[])).

1. Is there a way to enable thread contention monitoring for C#/.NET?
2. How do we compute similar metrics(blockedTime, waitedTime) for the C# Managed threads using C#/.NET APIs such as Performance Counter class and other relevant apis?

Comment: Basic statistics are available in Perfmon.exe,  ".NET LocksAndThreads" counters.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Concurrency Visualizer, if you're using Visual Studio.

The documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336027.aspx) describes how to use it.

It provides very rich thread statistics on blocking and synchronization.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out. I see it uses ETW(Events Tracing for Windows) under the hood.